# AR Plane Detection using Oculus Integration Unity SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, oculus

I am making MR(Mixed Reality) Tennis Game using Unity and Oculus Integration UnitySDK.
I made successfully the VR functions.
But when I use this SDK to handle AR Plane Detection functionality, it is too tricky to handle.
Is there anyone who has experience in AR integration using Oculus Integration Unity SDK?

I have tried AR Foundation for AR integration based on Oculus Integration installed for VR
But I found it is too hard to use AR Foundation with Oculus Integration SDK together.